# missing sbin/hotplug in Ubuntu

Tags: kernel, udev, hotplug

Im using Ubuntu and I cannot find `/sbin/hotplug`. Did anything replace it?
How does it handle hotplugging? I read that kernel calls it for notifying user space when an hotplug event happens. I also checked `/proc/sys/kernel/hotplug` , but its empty

Comment: [hotplugging](http://linux-hotplug.sourceforge.net/) is a standard feature of GNU/Linux. If you want to see where is located try `find / -name "*hotplug*"`

Answer (score 5):

From https://www.kernel.org/doc/pending/hotplug.txt we can read:

```
... Linux provides two interfaces to hotplug; the kernel can spawn a usermode
helper process, or it can send a message to an existing daemon listening to a
netlink socket.
```

and:

```
It's possible to disable the usermode helper hotplug mechanism 
(by writing an empty string into /proc/sys/kernel/hotplug)...
```

So, if your `/proc/sys/kernel/hotplug` is empty that means you/ubuntu are not using the 'usermode helper hotplug mechanism'.

Instead [udev](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Udev), as the "successor" of the old 'usermode helper hotplug mechanism', listens on a [netlink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netlink) socket and gets notified by the kernel about hotplug events.

I hope this helps.